# Inner Joins on multiple tables not returning rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anything wrong with this query? I was all working until I have Truncated my database and now I have only one record in it and when I run this query in phpmyadmin it returns 0 rows.

What am I missing?

```
SELECT 
Users.id,
Users.firstname,
Users.lastname,
Users.email,
Users.age,
Users.phone,
Universities.Faculty AS university,
Internship.internship_type AS Internship,
City.city AS city,
Interest.interest AS interest,
Users.filename,
Users.reg_date 
        FROM Users 
        INNER JOIN City ON Users.city = City.key 
        INNER JOIN Universities ON Users.university = Universities.id 
        INNER JOIN Interes ON Users.interest = Interest.key 
        INNER JOIN Internship ON Users.internship_type = Internship.internship_type
            ORDER BY `Users`.`id` ASC;
```

Comment: Does this user have any interests/internships and is on an university? Otherwise use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: In the Users table it has all the information and all the columns are filled in with the proper data.

Answer (score 2):

There might not be data in all the tables so can you check it by using left join and be sure at least user table must have data: then one by one change left join to inner where you won't get data there will be the problem but if other table's data is optional then it's better to use left join:

```
SELECT 
    Users.id,
    Users.firstname,
    Users.lastname,
    Users.email,
    Users.age,
    Users.phone,
    Universities.Faculty AS university,
    Internship.internship_type AS Internship,
    City.city AS city,
    Interest.interest AS interest,
    Users.filename,
    Users.reg_date 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN City ON Users.city = City.key 
LEFT JOIN Universities ON Users.university = Universities.id 
LEFT JOIN Interes ON Users.interest = Interest.key 
LEFT JOIN Internship ON Users.internship_type = Internship.internship_type
ORDER BY `Users`.`id` ASC;
```

Comment: The problem was here where it should have been `Internship ON Users.internship_type = Internship.key`   and it was  `INNER JOIN Internship ON Users.internship_type = Internship.internship_type`

Comment: You can also see the mistake in your post at the last Left Join. That is how I noticed it. Thank you :)

Comment: This is all from your question what I just changed is INNER to LEFT but I have been getting same from the beginning, I am not getting any difference or do not understand properly.

Comment: Sure. I know that i did the mistake you just presented a way to select even where data is missing. My mistake was here `ON Users.internship_type = Internship.internship_type` . I was mismatching my columns